# Simplifying Query for Filter Selection

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I'm currently working on a filter form to display a set of products. The product name is located in TABLE a with the filter tags in TABLE b. As filters are selected, the query needs to return all products from table a that fits all criteria selected.

My current query is (this example has two filters selected):

```
SELECT a.genus
    ,a.botanical
FROM a
WHERE a.ID IN (
        SELECT filter.filtered
        FROM (
            SELECT b.ID AS filtered
                ,COUNT(*) c
            FROM b
            WHERE b.tag_ID = 1
                OR b.tag_ID = 2
            GROUP BY b.ID
            HAVING c = 2
            ) AS filtered
        )
```

So, first things first, this does work; I wonder, however, if I'm missing some stupidly easy way to simplify this query . . . or should I accept this and move on?

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f36d06/3)

I had attempted many different types of joins with no success.  If only one filter would ever be selected, and simple LEFT JOIN would be perfect.  I run into issues when I need to handle more than one filter selection.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be? It seems like your query is working fine..

Comment: It is working fine. I was really looking for a query that would not require tracking the number of filters selected (for "HAVING c = x"), though I'm not entirely sure that such a query would exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 using subquery:

```
SELECT a.genus, a.botanical
FROM a
WHERE a.ID IN (
            SELECT b.ID
            FROM b
            WHERE b.tag_ID = 1
                OR b.tag_ID = 2
            GROUP BY b.ID
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
        )
```

Solution 2 using INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT a.genus, a.botanical
FROM a INNER JOIN 
    (   SELECT b.ID
        FROM b
        WHERE b.tag_ID IN (1,2)
        GROUP BY b.ID
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ) b2
    USING(ID)
```

Comment: Solution 2 does have a quicker computation time than my current query.  This may be the best option if I still must compute the number of filters selected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with cross apply like this,

```
SELECT a.genus
    ,a.botanical
FROM a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT b.ID
        ,COUNT(*) c
    FROM b
    WHERE (
            b.tag_ID = 1
            OR b.tag_ID = 2
            )
        AND a.ID = b.id
    GROUP BY b.ID
    HAVING c = 2
    ) b
```